# Error when trying to access XAMPP from a network

Tags: xampp, lan, local-network

I get following error when trying to **`access Xampp from a network`** I've tried but does not get any idea how to resolve it. Any help??I really confused

> ## Access Forbidden :
>
> Access to the requested Object is only available from the local network. This setting can be configured in the file "httpd-xampp.conf".

Comment: The error seems very self explanatory. Have you tried editing the `httpd-xampp.conf` file?

Comment: yeah, but wondering what exactly to do there.

Comment: Follow the link clear and concise http://yeslinux.blogspot.com/2012/07/new-xampp-security-concept-solved.html

Comment: @ChrisSalij: No, it is not very self explanatory. It doesn't say whare the file is. Try to find it

Comment: my advice: at the end of httpd-xampp.conf, remove 'xampp' such that you get :

<LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:security|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">
        Require local
 ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</LocationMatch>


instead of 


#<LocationMatch "^/(?i(?:xampp|security|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">
#        Require local
# ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
#</LocationMatch>
now only you web/php pages are visible, and not the admin pages

Answer (score 92, accepted):

In your
**xampppath\apache\conf\extra** open file **httpd-xampp.conf** and find the below tag:

```
# Close XAMPP sites here
<LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:xampp|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from ::1 127.0.0.0/8 
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/HTTP_XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</LocationMatch>
```

and add

```
"Allow from all"
```

after Allow from ::1 127.0.0.0/8 {line}

Restart xampp, and you are done.

**In later versions of Xampp**

...you can simply remove this part

```
#
# New XAMPP security concept
#
<LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:xampp|security|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">
        Require local
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</LocationMatch>
```

from the same file and it should work over the local network.

Comment: But after adding that it takes me to the XAMPP homepage instead of whatever IP I provide it. I tried accessing my DLink router but I landed upon the XAMPP homepage after adding the **Allow from all** line to the file.

Comment: i cant able you get you give details

Comment: just for somebody information: i had also to set up the passwords in "/opt/lampp/lampp security" after adding this string. Thanks.

Comment: Only works when set up passwords in /opt/lampp/lampp security

Comment: Restarting your computer or XAMPP is a must!

Comment: People , now you need to update /opt/lampp/etc/extra/httpd-xampp.conf . Then it will work!

Comment: we commented the "Require local" with '#' => "#Require local" (without the quotes) and it solved the problem

Answer (score 41):

This solution worked well for me:
http://www.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=50902&p=196185#p196185

Edit /opt/lampp/etc/extra/httpd-xampp.conf and adding Require all granted line at bottom of block `<Directory "/opt/lampp/phpmyadmin">` to have the following code:

```
<Directory "/opt/lampp/phpmyadmin">
  AllowOverride AuthConfig Limit
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: don't forget to restart the LAMPP service by using this command: `sudo /opt/lampp/lampp restart`

Comment: This answer is valid for Latest versions- Apache 2.4

Answer (score 8):

This answer is for XAMPP on Ubuntu.

The manual for installation and download is on (site official)

```
http://www.apachefriends.org/it/xampp-linux.html
```

After to start XAMPP simply call this command:

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```

You should now see something like this on your screen:

```
Starting XAMPP 1.8.1...
LAMPP: Starting Apache...
LAMPP: Starting MySQL...
LAMPP started.
```

If you have this

```
Starting XAMPP for Linux 1.8.1...                                                             
XAMPP: Another web server daemon is already running.                                          
XAMPP: Another MySQL daemon is already running.                                               
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...                                                                    
XAMPP for Linux started
```

.  The solution is

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
```

And the restast with `sudo //opt/lampp/lampp restart`

You to fix most of the security weaknesses simply call the following command:

```
/opt/lampp/lampp security
```

After the change this file

```
sudo kate //opt/lampp/etc/extra/httpd-xampp.conf
```

Find and replace on

```
    #
# New XAMPP security concept
#
<LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:xampp|security|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from ::1 127.0.0.0/8 
    Allow from all
    #\
    #   fc00::/7 10.0.0.0/8 172.16.0.0/12 192.168.0.0/16 \
    #   fe80::/10 169.254.0.0/16

    ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</LocationMatch>
```

Comment: `/opt/lampp/lampp security ` is very useful after you setup XAMPP ! It'll take care of several default security issues: FTP account, PHPAdmin, Sqlite account

Comment: I tried both of these solutions and neither resolved the error. After writing the changes to the file on the remote server, is there something else I need to do?

Comment: Relaunch xampp? What is the new error that you have now?