# Connecting socket.io over network for testing?

Tags: javascript, html, socket.io

So I'm trying to test out my socket.io website and on the website I have

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:82/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

....

var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:82');
```

just like on the socket.io example.  This works fine when I test on my localhost machine, but when I use another machine on the same network, I can only get to the website, but socket won't connect.  What am I doing wrong?

I am assuming that

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:82/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

should be

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

but that doesn't work an the browser assumes that I want to retrieve that .js file page from the website rather than what it's supposed to do.  Why does

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

not work on my website (xampp/codeigniter) when it's in the socket.io example client?

Comment: Can you paste the code you are using on the other machine? (I presume it doesn't also contain 'localhost' in the URL, otherwise you'd be asking that machine to connect to itself.)

Comment: the other machine is simply accessing this website through a browser through an address like 192.168.x.x

Comment: @Derek: Whatever the page is fetched from, connecting to `localhost` will connect to the computer you're connecting on, so it's not the same computer as the first. What about changing `localhost` to `192.168.something`?

Comment: So I have an app called chat at localhost/chat.  When I go to localhost/chat or 192.168.x.x/chat on the developer/server machine, it works fine, but when I go to another machine on the same network and load 192.168.x.x/chat, the website loads, but the socket.io.js resource is never loaded, therefore I assume <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:82/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script> is incorrect, however, I've tried <script type="text/javascript" src="192.168.x.x:82/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script> and that doesn't work either.  Not really sure how to load socket.io.js now

Comment: and since I'm using socket.io 0.8.4, I don't think <script type="text/javascript"  src="http://cdn.socket.io/stable/socket.io.js" ></script> will work either

Comment: @Derek: You should also change `io.connect('http://192.168.x.x:82/')`.

Comment: the io part isn't even recognized until socket.io.js is loaded which isn't

Comment: @Derek: So, on your machine, `http://localhost:82/socket.io/socket.io.js` works, but on another machine, `http://192.168.x.x:82/socket.io/socket.io.js` does not?

Comment: Could this be a firewall issue, where the server doesn't let traffic from outside localhost through to port 82, even though it does on port 80? and remember to qualify those addresses with http://

Comment: @Fuu interesting... i'll look into that, is this common because I'm using xampp for the server and cygwin to start the socket.io server, both xampp and cygwin are allowed through the firewall

Comment: don't think it's the firewall thing

Answer (score 1):

Are you using XAMPP? You need to allow access remotely - [new xammpp security concept](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083323/new-xampp-security-concept)

Anyway, I am doing something similar and this works for me - just change from localhost to the ip address of the machine running the web server.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="192.168.1.23:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
this.socket = new io.connect('192.168.1.23:8080');
```