# Access to the requested object is only available from the local network phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

I just installed xampp 1.8.0 for linux and when I opened phpmyadmin I got this error
Access Forbidden!!

```
New XAMPP security concept:

Access to the requested object is only available from the local network.

This setting can be configured in the file "httpd-xampp.conf".
```

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083323/new-xampp-security-concept) post but with no luck. please help. I am opening it from my own PC not from any other network.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error when trying to access XAMPP from a network](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083323/error-when-trying-to-access-xampp-from-a-network)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

open your http.conf file

```
vim /opt/lampp/etc/extra/httpd-xampp.conf
```

Comment "**Deny from all**" in the following section,

```
#
# New XAMPP security concept
#
<LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:xampp|security|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">
        Order deny,allow
       #Deny from all
        Allow from ::1 127.0.0.0/8 \
                fc00::/7 10.0.0.0/8 172.16.0.0/12 192.168.0.0/16 \
                fe80::/10 169.254.0.0/16

        ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</LocationMatch>
```

**Edit:**
Try to add "Allow from all" before "ErrorDocument" line.
Hope it helps.

Comment: @Sekar I'm afraid! Won't it allow other people from my ISP to handle XAMPP contents?

Comment: If this still doesn't work, change the file permission will do the trick.

Comment: @SantoshKumar yes it will. I'm trying to deny access to the Xampp folder as well.

Comment: I think what you need to add is `Require all granted` instead of `Require local`.

Comment: "Require local" is what is causing this issue.

Answer (score 58):

If you see below error message, when try into `phpyAdmin`:

```
New XAMPP security concept:
Access to the requested directory is only available from the local network.
This setting can be configured in the file "httpd-xampp.conf".
```

You can do next (for XAMPP, deployed on the UNIX-system):
You can try change configuration for `<Directory "/opt/lampp/phpmyadmin">`

```
# vi /opt/lampp/etc/extra/httpd-xampp.conf
```

and change security settings to

```
#LoadModule perl_module        modules/mod_perl.so

<Directory "/opt/lampp/phpmyadmin">
    AllowOverride AuthConfig Limit
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</Directory>
```

First - comment pl module, second - change config for node Directory. 
After it, you should restart `httpd` daemon

```
# /opt/lampp/xampp restart
```

Now you can access http://[server_ip]/phpmyadmin/

Comment: I've update as your guide but it still doesn't work, Could you give me a look? https://imgur.com/a3SOdNb

Comment: Why are you telling people to comment out the Perl module? I don't see how that's relevant.

Comment: i just copied and replaced this with this 
<Directory "/opt/lampp/phpmyadmin">
    AllowOverride AuthConfig Limit
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</Directory>

Comment: This is the right answer for XAMPP 7.4.7 the most voted answer didn't solve my problem

Answer (score 39):

Nothing worked for me but following thing was awesome:

1) Open

> httpd-xampp.conf

which is at

> /opt/lampp/etc/extra/

2) Find `<Directory "/opt/lampp/phpmyadmin">`

3) Now just add Require all granted before

4) So the code will look like this
    `<Directory "/opt/lampp/phpmyadmin">
    AllowOverride AuthConfig Limit
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>`

5) Now finally Restart the xampp with this command /opt/lampp/lampp restart

That's it and you are Done!

It also work with xampp. :)

Comment: The "Require all granted" was what made it work for me.

Answer (score 28):

Adding to Sekar answer

**Don't forget to restart your XAMPP Server**

Update the accepted answer :

now you need to comment Require local

```
#
# New XAMPP security concept
#
<LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:xampp|security|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">
        #Require local
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
```

Answer (score 18):

on osx log into your terminal and execute

```
sudo nano /opt/lampp/etc/extra/httpd-xampp.conf
```

and replace

```
<Directory "/opt/lampp/phpmyadmin">
    AllowOverride AuthConfig Limit
    Require local
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</Directory>
```

with this

```
<Directory "/opt/lampp/phpmyadmin">
    AllowOverride AuthConfig Limit
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</Directory>
```

and then restart apache and mysql

or use this command

```
 /opt/lampp/xampp restart
```

Answer (score 6):

> Hey,  use these section of code.
>
> Path for xampp is: apache\conf\extra\httpd-xampp.conf

```
 <LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:xampp|security|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
        #Allow from ::1 127.0.0.0/8 \
             #      fc00::/7 10.0.0.0/8 172.16.0.0/12 192.168.0.0/16 \
               #    fe80::/10 169.254.0.0/16

        ErrorDocument 403 /error/HTTP_XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
    </LocationMatch>
```

Answer (score 6):

The solution above are right but the challenge has been locating the particular file.

visit for mac
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OVGCXYZ-BoI

visit for windows
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MvYyEPaNNhE

INSTRUCTION (If not interested in video)

> > MAC

Steps

1. Start your xampp application
2. Start services

[image]

3. Click on the Volumes menu
4. Click mount
5. Click Explore

[image]

> > *N.B* It opens the opt/lampp/ window
> > [image]

6. Open the following directory to locate file
   lamp/etc/extra/httpd-xampp-conf
7. Open the file with any IDE of your choice e.g Visual Studio or PhpStorm or Text-Editor
8. Locate below code and replace the `Require local` with `Require all granted`.

> > > `Alias /phpmyadmin "D:/server/phpMyAdmin/" <Directory "D:/server/phpMyAdmin"> AllowOverride AuthConfig Require local ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var </Directory>`

9. Ensure you restart all services
10. Reload your page and Whuala.....It works

Comment: Thanks for the screenshots and easy-to-follow steps.

Answer (score 3):

I newer version of xampp you may use another method first open your httpd-xampp.conf file and find the string "phpmyadmin" using ctrl+F command (Windows).
and then replace this code

```
Alias /phpmyadmin "D:/server/phpMyAdmin/"
<Directory "D:/server/phpMyAdmin">
    AllowOverride AuthConfig
    Require local
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</Directory>
```

with this

```
Alias /phpmyadmin "D:/server/phpMyAdmin/"
<Directory "D:/server/phpMyAdmin">
    AllowOverride AuthConfig
    Require all granted
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</Directory>
```

**Don't Forget to Restart your Xampp.**

Answer (score 2):

after putting "Allow from all", you need to restart your xampp to apply the setting. thanks

Answer (score 0):

On Xampp 5.6.3 Windows
Path C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-xampp.conf
comment in this: #Require local

> New XAMPP security concept
>   ...
>           #Require local
>   ...

Answer (score 0):

Not need to change all config in file `/opt/lampp/etc/extra/httpd-xampp.conf.`
The only thing you need to change is the `Require local`
It's kinda obvious what Require local means so just change to `Require all granted`
Require all granted

***Solution***

from `Require local`  to `Require all granted`