# how to convert local html to pdf?

Tags: php, html, pdf, local

I've been searching for this feature over a long time, but I've found nothing I could use. I need an app, a service, a trick...whatever to help me transform html files that are produced in a local Apache server to pdf.

I've found one or two apps, but they have serious non-CSS support, so they are out of suggestion.

Has anyone achieved what I want to do?

**EDIT**

Actually, after long long searching, I've found the following solution:

1. use [pdfcrowd](http://pdfcrowd.com) (I used the SAVE-TO-PDF-LINK)
2. in order to make pdfcrowd fetch your local php-generated HTML pages, you have to adjust your Apache server settings (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11999371/access-to-the-requested-object-is-only-available-from-the-local-network-phpmyadm))
3. make your local page be browsed by a public IP (I used some minor network engineering help, actually it was a port forwarding)
4. that's it! you're done! as long as you access your application from the new public IP, the PHP->HTML->PDF will work fine!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert HTML + CSS to PDF with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/391005/convert-html-css-to-pdf-with-php)

Comment: @Rangad yeap. it might be possible, although that post doesn't specify that the solution should apply to local installation, not using any online calls to web services.

Comment: Try using: [DOMPDF](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf)

Answer (score 4):

I have used [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/) with some success. Works with the webkit so the support for CSS is decent.

Answer (score -1):

Try using [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/). Its CSS support is limited but is enough to create simple nice-looking documents. I have used it successfully in a few projects of mine.

```
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
$pdf->AddPage();
$html = '<div style="text-align:center">The words "<span style="font-weight: bold">[mazel] [tov]</span>" mean "Congratulations!"</div>';
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
```

Check out the [examples](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples.php).