# Why can't I access Xampp's phpmyadmin on localhost? Access is forbidden.

Tags: linux, ubuntu, phpmyadmin, xampp

I can access localhost fine on Xampp with phpmyadmin on ubuntu.  I can see the contents of /htdocs which I completely cleared and wrote my own for.  I want to access phpmyadmin, but cannot.

When loading phomyadmin, I am greeted by a 403 Error and a note advising me to configure the setting in the file `httpd-xampp.conf`.  I looked in `/opt/lampp/etc/extra/httpd-xampp.conf`, but have no idea what to configure.

Two areas within the file seem useful in this scenario:

```
<Directoy "/opt/lampp/phpmyadmin">
    AllowOverride AuthConfig Limit
    Order allow,deny
    Deny From all
</Directory>
```

and

```
#
# New XAMPP security concept
#

<LocationMatch "^/(?:xampp|security|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from ::1 127.0.0.0/8 \
    fc00::/7 10.0.0.0/8 172.16.0.0/12 192.168.0.0/16 \
    fe00::/10 169.254.0.0/16

    ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</LocationMatch>
```

In both segments I tried changing "Deny from all" to "Allow from all" and restarted Xampp with the command `sudo /opt/lampp/lampp restart`.  I received the same error page as before.  I tried other solutions found online, but none have worked.

What do I have to configure to access phpmyadmin?

Comment: maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12385829/1703313

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[The solution can be found here](http://www.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=50902&p=196185#p196185).  Summary follows:

Edit `/opt/lampp/etc/extra/httpd-xampp.conf`.

Add the line `Require all granted` to the bottom of the `<Directory "/opt/lampp/phpmyadmin">` block as follows:

```
<Directory "/opt/lampp/phpmyadmin">
  AllowOverride AuthConfig Limit
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: That worked for me (I write this because this answer is actually not accepted -> to show everybody that this is working).

Comment: Someone also pointed out that the new line (Require...) should replace the previous 2 lines (Order... and Allow...)

Comment: works on windows too^^ (obviously change path to relevant path)

Answer (score 3):

I solved this by creating a new virtual host for `phpmyadmin`

### For windows systems:

Append the following to `C:/xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf`:

```
NameVirtualHost phpmyadmin.local

<VirtualHost phpmyadmin.local>
  ServerName phpmyadmin.local
  DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/phpmyadmin"
  <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/phpmyadmin">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Change the `DocumentRoot/Directory` to the path where you have installed your version of `phpmyadmin`.

Open the `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` file in a text editor and add the following line:

```
127.0.0.1     phpmyadmin.local
```

then save the hosts file and restart `xampp`.

Comment: Thank you, this was the only solution that worked for me. However, phpmyadmin was at ```C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin``` in my case.

Answer (score 0):

## Try this

New XAMPP security concept

Search in httpd-xampp.conf

```
<LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:xampp|security|phpmyadmin|licenses|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">
        Require local
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</LocationMatch>
```

## Replace with or remove phpmyadmin

```
<LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:xampp|security|licenses|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">
        Require local
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</LocationMatch>
```