# 403 Forbidden on PHPMyAdmin in Puppy Linux

Tags: linux, phpmyadmin, xampp, http-status-code-403

I have installed XAMPP in TahrPup. I need this for a class, but being the only one who runs Linux I can't get help from others in class or the instructor.

I'm getting a `403 Forbidden error` accessing `127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin/` and `localhost/phpmyadmin`, or even just trying to access `127.0.0.1` and `localhost`.

Version: XAMPP for Linux 5.6.3-0

I did check that Apache and MySQL and stuff is started (running `xampp start`).

I have tried based on other answers editing `httpd-xampp.conf` under `<LocationMatch ...` to say

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from ::1 127.0.0.0/8 
Allow from all
```

And in `httpd.conf` it says

```
<Directory "/opt/lampp/apache2/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

... this was already the configuration, and most answers said to change it -to- this, which it already was.

I can post config files if needed. I'm just to the point of not knowing where to start anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated here:
[Why can't I access Xampp's phpmyadmin on localhost? Access is forbidden.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12307842/why-cant-i-access-xampps-phpmyadmin-on-localhost-access-is-forbidden?rq=1#comment23322133_14602948)
The lines

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

needed to be removed.  Okay.