# How to make your website online using XAMPP & ROUTER? (already tried the steps but the result is..)

Tags: web, xampp, port, portforwarding, port80

Can someone help me?

I already tried this steps:

1. Open Port 80

   - Set rules in windows firewall (inbound rules, port 80, both protocols, allow connection, etc..)
2. Port forwarding

   - Port 80 & 443 enabled

but I still cannot access my server.

I used "Open Port Check Tool" of CanYouSeeMe.org to check if it is open, the result: `Connection timed out`

- Pinged my external ip address on external computers, the result: `Request timed out`

Images showing the logs:

[image: I could not see service]
[image: Request timed out]
[image: config]

Answer (score 0):

Do a google search for your ISP + port 80. Chances are pretty big that your ISP doesn't allow it for security reasons.

A way around this is to host on a different port than 80.

Comment: Yes, but if your ISP blocks it, then it won't matter if you forwarded it. All requests on port 80 to your IP will get filtered out by your ISP's firewall. :) If your ISP doesn't block those requests, then you probably missed a router or firewall in your home network. (sometimes there are more then you think)

Comment: So sir, I will change the port of the XAMPP. My question is, any port? Or number? Does it mind at all what port number is? Or do you have a better suggestion for the port number?

Comment: I suggest using something like 8080, http://veerasundar.com/blog/2009/07/how-to-change-xampp-server-port/

Comment: Still, I cannot access the server.. Changed the port to 8080, open the port 8080, portforwarding..

Answer (score 0):

If it is not your ISP blocking port 80, maybe XAMPP isn't allowing connections other than the ones comming from your localhost. Take a look at this [Error when trying to access XAMPP from a network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083323/error-when-trying-to-access-xampp-from-a-network)

Comment: Maybe because I don't have a public ip? Or external ip = public ip?  Still, doesn't work..

Comment: If you are running your server on your local network, then the ip shown @ http://www.whatismyip.com/ is your public/external ip. If somebody wants to visit your site, they should launch a request to `http://yourip:port/site-context.` The port forwarding tells your router to send the incomming requests to the appropriate pc on your local network, so make sure that it points to the right ip. The only things that can block the request by my knowledge are : Firewalls server, configuration XAMPP, Firewall Router, Firewall ISP. You should be able to check them one by one.

Comment: I already checked the firewalls server, configuration XAMPP, Firewall Router.. Maybe its the ISP's firewall?

Comment: Some of my friends said that I have to use VPS to do what I wanna do because I'm having a problem to make our website online because it uses some softwares that aren't permitted to be uploaded or if it can be uploaded, it is not permitted to access.