# PHP : Can't access phpmyadmin on a local network: Forbidden

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, xampp

I am able to access /phpmyadmin normally from the computer which is running the XAMPP server, but when I try to access it from another computer on the same network, I get the following error:

"Access Forbidden! 
New XAMPP Security Concept: 
Access to the requested object is only available from the local network.

This setting can be configured in the file "httpd-xampp.conf"."

I have edited the httpd-xampp.conf file as per this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083323/error-when-trying-to-access-xampp-from-a-network), but it's still giving the same error using these arguments:

```
# since XAMPP 1.4.3
<Directory "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/phpmyadmin">
    Require local
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You need to update from **require local** to **Require all grante**d in the LocationMatch inside httpd-xampp.conf.

2) If still you have problem, remove **Deny from all** and add **Allow from all**

Answer (score -1):

yes.. 
You need to update from **require local** to ***Require all granted*** in the `LocationMatch` inside `httpd-xampp.conf`