# XAMPP htdocs and Localhost is two different folders on mac

Tags: php, xampp, localhost

All I want to do is get XAMPP work with localhost.

I can reach my  via Library -> WebServer -> Documents and XAMPP -> htdocs via http://xxx.xxx.xx.x/ (x = my ip address).

One problem is that I can't use PHPAdmin or mySQL due security risk.

I know I have been fiddling around before I installed XAMPP and I don't know how to reset/reinstall to default settings.

Thanks in advance

Comment: "_One problem is that I can't use PHPAdmin or mySQL due security risk._" what security risk? You will need to locate your `httpd.conf` file for apache and modify the `<Directory>` rules

Answer (score 0):

Got this message:

Access Forbidden :

Access to the requested object is only available from the local network. This setting can be configured in the file "httpd-xampp.conf".

And found this topic:
[Error when trying to access XAMPP from a network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083323/error-when-trying-to-access-xampp-from-a-network)

But I found it to much work. I installed the Mamp instead. Works just fine. https://www.mamp.info/en/